# Force command to make newline

Tags: bash

I am currently automating a tool via a bash script. The program prints out the process in a very ugly format and I want to parse it to a better one (it outputs the progress as an integer from 0 to 65535) and display real percentage. The problem: The program does not generate newlines, it will, i guess, just jump to the beginning of the line and overwrite it to only create one line of progress output.

What I mean by that is that the process will not generate newlines so my loop:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    parse_output_of_the_line
    echo "${progress}"
done < <(process --with-params)
```

Wont produce any output as of the missing newline.

Is there a way to force that this will be interpreted as newline?

Comment: What do you mean about \b?  \b is just b in shell terminology.  ^b would be character \001, which is translatable.

Comment: why don't you add an `echo` after the `dostuff` line to produce it?

Comment: Edited the question again. There is an echo in the code, sorry for missing that out. the problem is there is NEVER a newline.

Comment: It sounds almost like your incoming process is a stream(?). Perhaps something in [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8618/script-that-keep-reading-a-stream) might help

Comment: thanks. with the help of this answer I figured it out. I will update the question with the answer shortly

Comment: The answer is fair, solves the problem, but the question is not good for the next person wanting to do what you did.   You basically are processing a stream byte by byte in bash, which has a lot of overhead.   I'm sure there's a better question for the ages here.

Comment: @BenPen: Feel free to edit it. I dont know how I could have described my problem better as I did not know it was streaming at the point where I asked.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the comments in the question i was able to solve the problem. The solution for me was to read byte by byte and append it together to a line like this:

```
linefeed="$(echo -e "\r")"
temp_line=""
while IFS= read -rn 1 char; do
    if [ "${char}" == "${linefeed}" ]; then
        line="${temp_line}"
        temp_line=""

        # DO YOUR STUFF HERE!

    else
        temp_line="${temp_line}${char}"
    fi
done < <(command --with-params)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use tr to filter the output.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    parse_output_of_the_line
    echo "${progress}"
done < <(process --with-params | tr '\r' '\n')
```

This has the advantage of being easy to use with normally formatted lines as well.  If you detect when the progress reporting is done, you could reformat the output in a different way by adding logic inside the while loop.